# ATK4 - Update a form field value based on change in related dropdown

Tags: jquery, forms, atk4

I am trying to fill in a form field with a certain value from my DB whenever a related dropdown changes and I don't understand why:

- I can successfully use the js()->val() of my dropdown to set the val() of the field I'm trying to populate ($price)
- but whenever I use the js()->val() in my query or in the alert I added for troubleshooting purposes, it outputs the field name reference string with '.val()' appended or something similar...

I know it's a noob question but I've looked at this several ways and tried different ways and I can't get it to work.
If I hardcode a value for 'id' in the query below it does work as expected, I just need to be able to pass the query the appropriate value...

```
$form = $this->add('Form');
$product = $form->addField('dropdown', 'name');
$product->setModel('Product');
$price = $form->addField('line', 'price_per');
$product->js('change', $price->js()
    ->val($product->js()->val())
    ->univ()
    ->alert('ID is : ' . $product->js()->val()));   

// $product->js('change', $price->js()->val(
    // $this->api->db->dsql() //->expr(2+2)
    // ->debug()
    // ->table('product')
    // ->field('price_per')
    // ->where('id',$product->js()->val())
    // ->getOne()
    // ));
```

Comment: Okay: if I eliminate the 'string' component of the alert, in other words I change the alert to:
    ->alert($product->js()->val())

Then it outputs the ID I am expecting... So the question becomes, how do I apply this to the query?

Comment: using ->debug in the middle of the chain should help you. Also check out how _enclose() works.

Comment: Thanks Romans.

Okay, reading about _enclose here: https://agiletoolkit.org/learn/understand/chains/enclose

I understand its purpose and how it would help me, however I'm not sure how or where to use it in my current code to get there.
Any pointers or doc pages I can look at to help me figure it out?

Comment: I'm still banging my head against a wall here, I'm all about 'teaching a man to fish' instead of just handing him the fish, but I certainly wouldn't mind being slapped in the face with a fish right about now :)

Anyone able to help me get started here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
->alert('ID is : ' . $product->js()->val()));
```

you must remember that js() produces a PHP chain which can then be converted into javascript. If you concatenate it with string, then it becomes a string and hence the alert. Try this:

```
->alert($product->js()->val()));
```

it should work fine.

You can add method in the UNIV chain with necessary concatenation. You can also use js(null,' 2+4') to inject any javascript code, but be careful as it is not escaped.

**AJAX**

This is a technique when javascript relies on server-side algorithm. JavaScript sends request to the backend. Agile Toolkit uses a technique called AJAXEC (Ajax + Exec). It will send request to the server, but server will respond with chunk of javascript for it to execute (hence the ->execute() method)

There are several ways to wrap this functionality with Agile Toolkit but you should probably look at the basics first:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1P3mx9s_aA
- http://agiletoolkit.org/codepad/interaction/reloading
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/agile-toolkit-devel/%22-%3Eon%22/agile-toolkit-devel/31k6QoUdZRg/zVbgi2h6kTAJ

Comment: Right, I got that, but I'm stuck on how to apply that principle to my dsql in the part of the code that's commented out above.

Comment: You need to understand that some code is happening on the server, and other in the browser and they need to logically call each-other. I added some links to help.